# Finding the solutions of $\cos (x) +x = a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, roots

What is the approach to finding the solutions of the following function? I was not able to analytically resolve the solutions - but rather resorted to a graphical approach.

$$\cos (x) + x = 1$$
or in general where $a$ could be any real number,
$$\cos(x) + x = a.$$

**EDIT**:

Or when more than one solution exists. 
$$\cos (\pi x) + x = a.$$

Comment: The first equation has just one root: $x=0$.

Comment: You have several choices: 1) Graphical method. 2) Numerical methods ([bisection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), [Newton method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method), etc). 3) Taylor series expansion of inverse function. (2) is covered in most calculus texts .

Comment: The usage of the term "root" is incorrect here. You are seeking solutions, not roots.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numerical root finding is a perfectly good way to go. If you want to solve

$\cos (x) + x = a$

you can do a little shuffling to get

$a - \cos(x) = x$

Since $\cos(x)$ will be a number between $-1$ and $1$, you know that that $a - \cos(x)$ will be between $a-1$ and $a + 1$. That means that the $x$ you're looking for must be in the interval $[a-1, a+1]$. Once you know that, a few steps of bisection followed by Newton's method should get you a very accurate answer very fast.

Comment: Thank you, this makes good sense. I added an additional question to the original post regarding a more complex, but related, example.